# Pass string into Range Function in VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, range

I am trying to create a range in a function but the range varies so I am going to pass in the definition as a string but I am running into an error because it says it "Expected an array".  So, I thought this was because the double quotes weren't included so I tried to include them in the string by doubling up on double quotes but now VBA is saying I have an invalid character in that string (that being the first dollar sign).  I am really confused on how to fix this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
gRange = ""$A$1:$F$2""
```

Comment: Can you show the function header and the call to it? You shouldn't have to  use double quotes.

Comment: What is **gRange**? It might be array variable....

Comment: at least show the code you have for your function... And if it expects an ayyay, maybe `Sheets("whatever").range(gRange).value` is the array. Also forget double quotes , gRange is a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have issues in VBA with extra quotes in strings, I always fall back on using `Chr(34)` to replace.

```
gRange = Chr(34) & "$A$1:$F$2" & Chr(34)
```

[Chr() MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: `ChartData.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range(Range)`

Comment: `gRange` is passed in as `Range` in the function

Comment: @NeilCaffrey I'm not sure you can use the variable `Range` like that because it is already "protected".  What happens if you use `ChartData.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range(gRange)`

Comment: I ended up finding a solution using an IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using an if Statement like so:

```
If sheetName = "Totals" Then
ChartData.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("$A$1:$F$2")
Else
ChartData.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("$A$1:$G$2")
End If
```

Instead of using a string.